# Automated CSS analysis - Which properties can contain URLs?

Tags: c#, css

I'm running an automated CSS analysis using CSS parsing in C#, and for that I need to know the full list of class properties that can contain URLs. I could not find such a list anywhere on the net.

So far I've come up with:

- `background` : url()
- `background-image` : url()
- `border` : url()
- `border-image` : url()
- `list-style` : url()
- `list-style-image` : url()

Is this it or are there [more](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_all.asp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/propidx.html

Searching on this page for "uri" shows these:

- background-image
- content
- cue-after
- cue-before
- cursor
- line-style-image
- play-during

and then in CSS3 there's this one that you said but I'm not sure about any others.

- border-image-source

Comment: Pretty sure there's *waaaaay* more than that in CSS3 (even if you're looking at just one of the many dozens of specifications).

Comment: Yeah I think so as well but can't find a page that lists all of the properties of the new stuff